# Updating state in React is causing abnormal results from setInterval function

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, setinterval

I am trying to create a stopwatch functionality. I am using the setInterval function to increment my timer variable per 1000ms. Everything works very well at this point. However, when I try to include the state that needs to be updated, into the setInterval function; it breaks the code and starts printing awkwardly and inconsistently.

I have included my codes below. I commented out the lines that were causing errors. Everything works well until I uncomment those lines. I really need to understand what is going on.

```
import { useState } from "react"

function Timer() {
  const [time, setTime] = useState({
    hr: 0,
    min: 0,
    sec: 0
  })
  const timeCalc = {
    seconds: 0,
    minutes: 0,
    hours: 0,
    timeCount() {
  let interval = setInterval(() => {
      this.seconds++
      console.log(this.seconds)
      // setTime({ ...time, sec: this.seconds })
      if (this.seconds === 60) {
        this.seconds = 0
        // setTime({ ...time, sec: 0 })
        this.minutes++
        // setTime({ ...time, min: this.minutes })
      }
      if (this.minutes === 60) {
        this.minutes = 0
        // setTime({ ...time, min: 0 })
        this.hours++
        // setTime({ ...time, hr: this.hours })
      }
    }, 1000)    
   }
  }
    timeCalc.timeCount()
  

  return (
    <div>
      <span>{`00${time.hr} : `.slice(-5)}</span>
      <span>{`00${time.min} : `.slice(-5)}</span>
      <span>{`00${time.sec}`.slice(-2)}</span>
    </div>
  )
}
export default Timer
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are some problems with your code in order to this to work

- Your interval is executing each time some state changes, you need to put inside an useEffect to timeCalc.timeCount() executes once
- This change require that you pay attention to the dependencies in useEffect as we need that execute it once we pass an empty array to useEffect, but linter complains it say that timeCalc is a dependency and we need to add it, but being an object is going to execute useEffect eachTime it evaluates prev object === current object (because it always be different) so we need to put timeCalc inside the useEffect (check the code below)
- Once we move the timeCalc object inside the useEffect, useEffect (linter) complains with "time" state that is outside the useEffect, we could add time to use effect but objects are not a good type to pass to dependencies array because they will always be different (even if they have the same properties), in order to solve this we can add a functional update to setTime, functional update is a function that receives the prev state and you should return the new state based on that (check the code below)
- Its a good practice to clear the interval **(and necessary for preventing unexpected behavior)** when component is unmounted (return inside useEffect with clearInterval)

Code with fixes:

```js
import { useState, useEffect } from "react";

function Timer() {
  const [time, setTime] = useState({
    hr: 0,
    min: 0,
    sec: 0,
  });

  useEffect(() => {
    const timeCalc = {
      seconds: 0,
      minutes: 0,
      hours: 0,
      timeCount: function() {
        console.log('executing');
        return setInterval(() => {
          this.seconds++;
          setTime((time) => ({ ...time, sec: this.seconds }));
          if (this.seconds === 60) {
            this.seconds = 0;
            setTime((time) => ({ ...time, sec: 0 }));
            this.minutes++;
            setTime((time) => ({ ...time, min: this.minutes }));
          }
          if (this.minutes === 60) {
            this.minutes = 0;
            setTime((time) => ({ ...time, min: 0 }));
            this.hours++;
            setTime((time) => ({ ...time, hr: this.hours }));
          }
        }, 1000);
      },
    };

    const intervalId = timeCalc.timeCount();

    return () => {
      clearInterval(intervalId)
    }
  }, []);

  return (
    <div>
      <span>{`00${time.hr} : `.slice(-5)}</span>
      <span>{`00${time.min} : `.slice(-5)}</span>
      <span>{`00${time.sec}`.slice(-2)}</span>
    </div>
  );
}
export default Timer;
```

Here is the result in a codesandbox
https://codesandbox.io/s/dazzling-fire-68wjtf

Only some advice related to your code

- Always if it is possible split your objects in different minimal states (for example one state for seconds, one for minutes, one for hours)
- When your code has sideEffect (like interval, setTimeout, setState after evaluation, fetch an API) and you want to execute it almost immediately consider the use of useEffect
- Keep in mind the dependencies array in useEffect
- Remember to clear intervals when you use them
- Try to not work with `this` keyword if it is a functional component, probably it will be not necessary, instead you can work with const, let, states or refs

This will be the refactor after following this advice

```js
import { useState, useEffect } from "react";

function Timer() {
  const [seconds, setSeconds] = useState(0);
  const [minutes, setMinutes] = useState(0);
  const [hours, setHours] = useState(0);

  useEffect(() => {
    const intervalId = setInterval(() => {
      const newSeconds = seconds + 1;
      const newMinutes = minutes + 1;
      const newHours = hours + 1;
      setSeconds(newSeconds);
      if (newSeconds === 60) {
        setSeconds(0);
        setMinutes(newMinutes);
      }
      if (newMinutes === 60) {
        setMinutes(0);
        setHours(newHours);
      }
      if (newHours === 24) {
        setHours(0);
      }
    }, 1000);

    return () => {
      clearInterval(intervalId);
    };
  }, [seconds, minutes, hours]);

  return (
    <div>
      <span>{`00${hours} : `.slice(-5)}</span>
      <span>{`00${minutes} : `.slice(-5)}</span>
      <span>{`00${seconds}`.slice(-2)}</span>
    </div>
  );
}
export default Timer;
```

Code Sandbox
https://codesandbox.io/s/bold-mendel-fv3r2v?file=/src/App.js

Comment: Thank you very much for this detailed answer. I'd like to ask: why does setInterval run every time a state changes? Also, I'm very surprised at the additional advice for structuring my code. I actually wrote my state variables explicitly that way before, but proceeded to change it into objects in order to save space and make it look neater and more efficient? Isn't that a valid reason to use objects in place of single state variables?

Comment: Also, I don't get why you would advise against the use of the 'this' keyword?

Comment: why does setInterval run every time a state changes?
----
Because in the way that react works it execute components (function) each time something in  state changes, that's why the use (and the main goal) of useEffect, it is intended to manage when to execute a particular code

Comment: Isn't that a valid reason to use objects in place of single state variables? ----

you can structure in object or simple values the thing here is that object has special treatment e.g useEffect in his internal compares the values passed in dependencies array so if you pass an object it will compare with the prev object in order to execute or not again the useEffect, objects as dependencies always return that are different hence it always trigger useEffect, here you have two options passing in dependency object.value as a dependency or use primitive values to work with useEffect

Comment: Also, I don't get why you would advise against the use of the 'this' keyword? --- because "this" keyword in React is more intended to use with clases and are related to object oriented programming. with functions and functional programming doesn't have too much sense you can work and achieve all the things that you need without using "this". 

One of the main goals of introducing hooks, smart functional components and stop using class based components was to remove the use of "this" keyword because in javascript its use is confusing and also lead to unexpected behavior